# Log In / Sign Up on Splash screen?

Tags: login, mobile-application, splash-screen

Is it common to include Login / Sign Up actions on an app's splash screen? Or is it more efficient to first have a Splash screen, and then follow with a dedicated Log In / Sign Up page?

Answer (score 3):

Avoid a splash screen, they are more for show than they are useful. The login/sign up page should be the first thing the user see's (if they need to log in to access content, i.e Facebook), if the user can access the site without logging in, then do not force them - have the option else where.  So have a dedicated login page.

[Do we really need splash screens?](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/10/11/splash-pages-do-we-really-need-them/)

**EDIT**

[IOS how not to use splash screens - A 2014 article](https://fuzzproductions.com/news/ios-ux-how-not-to-use-launch-screens)

Comment: Not sure if I agree. Splash screens can have several functional purposes, e.g.: earn time for loading content in the back-end or simply use the splash as an 'eye candy' to support the visual appearance of a brand.

Also, splash screens for websites differ somewhat from splash screens for apps.

Comment: Plus, the article you were referring to is from 2007, a pre-mobile, pre-smartphone era in which the meaning of a splash screen was very different, and the mobile accessibility to information was very different. A splash screen, nowadays, is also a way to put a 'pause' or a time divider between one's transition from one app to another, from one action or event to another, etc.

Comment: They have a purpose around 1% of the time - freeing resources, making a network connection. If your app does not need these on start-up to work then do not do use it.  Agreed the article is old - but it highlights the same point - If you do not need to use one, don't.

Comment: Going back to your comment about a 'pause' I do not see why someone would benefit from a divider between apps.

Comment: I would agree that Splash Screens belong in the dim and distant past, along with Flash intros for websites.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest skipping the splash screen, as this will only delay the user. The answer to your login/signup question depends on the requirements of your application. Here are the various ways it could be done.

- If authentication is required to access any content on the application, because it will not function without it, then have a dedicated login/signup as your first screen.
- If login is only required for some of your applications features, then I would drop the user directly into your application. When a user attempts to use a feature where authentication is required, then ask them to login/signup.

Answer (score 0):

SIGN-UP should be first and big, because you want to acquire new customers, Sign-in is for regulars, used to the interface (upper-right corner), they know exactly where it is and most probable a cookie is giving them access anyway.

A great example of this is Digital Ocean homepage

> https://www.digitalocean.com/